# Est-ce qu'on utilise "y" ou "le" pour la préposition "à"

Tags: grammaire

On dit :

> Tu penses à fermer le salon ? => Tu y penses ?

Mais

> Je pense qu'il trouvera un emploi. => Je le pense.

Y a-t-il une règle pour l'emploi des pronoms « y » et « le » ?

Answer (score 1):

Il y a une règle et on la trouve en partie [ici](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-55948.php) (caractères gras dus à user LPH).

> **I** "Y" peut remplacer *un COI introduit par la préposition* **« à » (au, à la, à l', aux)**.
>
> au —   Croit-il au Père Noël ? Il **y** croit.
> à l' —  Paul va à l'école. => Il **y** va.
> à la —  T'intéresses-tu à la musique ? Oui, je m'**y** intéresse.
> aux —   Pascale vit aux Pays-Bas. => Elle **y** vit.
>
> **II** "Y" peut remplacer *un COI introduit par les prépositions* **« dans », « en », « sous », « sur », « devant »…**
>
> Nous sommes en classe. Nous **y** sommes.
> Le chat se cache sous la table. Il s'**y** cache.
> Je vais chez l'épicier. J'**y** vais.
> Mets la couverture sur le lit. Mets l'*y*.
>
> **III** Si la préposition introduit une personne, on utilisera les pronoms **"me", "te", "lui", "leur"…**
>
> Parles-tu à ta voisine ? Oui, je **lui** parle.
> Nicolas écrit à ses grands-parents. Il **leur** écrit.

« À fermer le salon » est un complément introduit par « à » ; donc « y » est utilisé.

En ce qui concerne le pronom "le" (pronom personnel), son emploi est indiqué lorsque sa fonction est celle de COD ([réf.](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-43671.php)). Ceci est vrai pour les pronoms suivants (qui sont listés avec leur forme alternative (l')).

> **le, la, les, l'** placés devant un verbe

- Il y a un animal sur la colline; il **le** voit avec ses jumelles.
- Donne lui sa pomme, il **la** mangera tout à l'heure.
- L'oiseau ne reste jamais près des chats, il **les** craint.

La subordonnée « qu'il trouvera un emploi » a pour fonction celle de COD dans la phrase et son genre est considéré comme neutre, donc "le" est utilisé.